# Java HTTP Request Stuck

Tags: java, http, request

I've never really used http requests in Java, I'm trying to make a request that would basically recreate this http://supersecretserver.net:8080/http://whateverwebsite.com
This server takes whatever website and returns only the text of the page in the body of the response.

The code is as follows:

```
public String getText(String webPage) throws ParseException, IOException{
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {        
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI("http://supersecretserver.net:8080/" + "http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/"));
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    String responseBody = "No text found on webpage.";
    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    switch(responseCode) {
    case 200:
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null) {
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Returning Response..");
    System.out.println(responseBody);
    return responseBody;
}
```

It seems to get stuck on

```
response = client.execute(request);
```

I'm not sure what the problems is, any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems likely that your `HttpClient` is not timing out, you can set a timeout value by following this example (from http://www.jayway.com/2009/03/17/configuring-timeout-with-apache-httpclient-40/)

You just to have to consider a timeout value that makes sense for you.

```java
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, connectionTimeoutMillis);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeoutMillis);
```

Also as your `HttpClient` is not connecting (since it's getting stuck) you should also take into consideration why is that happening (maybe you need to configure a proxy?)

Comment: Yes, I was assuming this. Thanks, I'll set the timeout and if it does timeout I will just have to configure my proxy I think.
In any case this makes complete sense, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't trying to work with broken code.